# What to put as GPA for job app

Tags: professionalism

So I'm currently applying for a job and instead of asking for your GPA or transcripts they ask you for a range in the form of check boxes like this:

```
0 - 0.9
1 - 1.9
2 - 2.9
3 - 4
```

I currently have a 2.97 GPA. Is it fair for me to round up .03 points and check the 3-4 range or do I really need to clump myself with the 2s?

Comment: I assume the form was designed by someone with a 0.5 GPA? ...

Comment: If they're clumping the 3.01's and the 4.0's in a single box, I'd say they don't really care about your GPA much if at all, it's just a formality. Check the top box and be done with it.

Comment: As its to one decimal place  2.97 is rounded up to 3 this is high school math

Comment: Can you check both?

Comment: Check 2-2.9. If they filter you out because you didn't check "3-4", you don't want to work there.

Answer (score 4):

Given the form shows 0.1 increments, you should round to 3 for the purposes of the application.  Just be prepared to explain why you did that if they ask in the interview.

Comment: +1 to `be prepared to explain why you did that if they ask in the interview.`

Comment: If I had to explain something so basic as how to round up numbers at an interview id probably not rate the company very highly.

Answer (score 4):

The survey uses an accuracy of 1 decimal place. At that accuracy, 2.97 is equivalent to 3.0.

Since you have a 3.0 GPA, you should tick the box for the range of "3-4".